# Can anyone help me identify these two Japanese fonts?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-identification, japanese

Can anyone help me indentify the two fonts that are used in the areas I circled? I’m hoping to find fonts that have the multiple outlines like the ones in the picture. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Damn it, I thought the bottom said "alarmy clock photo".

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.These outlines around the letters are more than likely not part of the font itself, but have been added in vector image editing software.